# With NHibernate how can I populate a complex type when using a stored proc?

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, nhibernate-mapping

I am using NHibernate with a stored procedure but I am having trouble populating a complex type.

When not using a stored proc I would set up the mapping like this...

```
 <property name="RoleEndDate"
  type="Mdl.Common.Persistence.EndDateUserType, Mdl.Common.Persistence">
  <column name="DateEnd"/>
  <column name="DateEndAssumed"/>
</property>
```

However when I try the same thing with sql-query mapping my EndDateUserType class fails as the column names passed to it are not found in the data reader. The names are the NHibernate generated names (eg. DateEnd14_0_) rather than the actual column names (DateEnd).

Is is possible to map to complex types when running with a stored proc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the columns in the sql-query part of the mapping file too, like this...

```
<return-property name="RoleEndDate">
    <return-column name="DateEnd" />
    <return-column name="DateEndAssumed" />
  </return-property>
```